# element with scrollLeft is scrolling faster than the rest of the document

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

I have an element which has a fixed position, but has the ability to scroll left and right using a jQuery calculation which I used from [this example on JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/F7Bme/)

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
var x = 0 - $(this).scrollLeft();
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

// whether that's below the form
if (y >= top) {
    // if so, ad the fixed class
    $('.scroll_fixed').addClass('fixed');
} else {
    // otherwise remove it
    $('.scroll_fixed').removeClass('fixed');
}

$(".scroll_fixed").offset({
    left: x + leftInit
});

});
```

The solution works well until I have to scroll to the left, where the element being scrolled "parallaxes" against the rest of the document - i.e, it scrolls about twice as fast as the rest of the document.

I know this is a problem with the jQuery calculation, but was wondering if anybody has come across this before? and if so, how did you tackle it? I am at a bit of a loss....

**edit**

problem solved - It was because the code was using $(window).scrollLeft(); instead of the parent element within the scope of the element i was wishing to manipulate.

the wrapper div was classed as "wrapperDiv", so I used $(".wrapperDiv").scrollLeft();

I would mark this question as asked, but as I am new to Stack Overflow i cannot answer for a further 7 hours....

Answer (score 0):

Just to flag this question as answered:

"It was because the code was using `$(window).scrollLeft();` instead of the parent element within the scope of the element i was wishing to manipulate. The wrapper div was classed as "wrapperDiv", so I used `$(".wrapperDiv").scrollLeft();`"